# VBA in Excel: How to replace a command with a variable?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm building a function that retrieves table elements from a web-page. That works quite fine so far.

To make the function more versatile, I would like to be able to call it using parameters telling it what to look for.

My current code writes the values found into the cell using:

```
Sub RetrieveWebPage Parameter

... some code here

   rng.Value = cl.innerHTML

... some code here
End Sub
```

How can I replace the "innerHTML" with a variable parameter so that it retrieves not always the innerHTML element, but possibly the outerHTML, or the Title, etc.?

I tried this

```
rng.Value = cl.Parameter
```

but just get the error that the Object does not support this property or method. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim P As String
P = "innerHTML"

rng.Value = CallByName(cl, P, vbGet)
```

Comment: Awesome, that was exactly what I was looking for :) Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
Sub RetrieveWebPage (Parameter as String)
'... some code here
Select Case Parameter
    Case "Inner"
        rng.Value = cl.innerHTML
    Case "Outer"
        rng.Value = cl.outerHTML
    Case "Title"
        rng.Value = cl.Title
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Call the programmer and suggest adding error-handling to this routine or using a class"
End Select
'... some code here
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was thinking of something like this, though I went for now with Tim Williams solution as this is what I was exactly looking for. I believe though, your version is probably the more stable and "clean" version to use

Answer (score 1):

All due respect to @Doug, but I prefer to use Boolean variables for this sort of thing.  Primarily because a Boolean variable can be only False or True (defaults to false when declared).  The advantage to this is you don't have to worry about accidentally passing a misspelled String as a parameter which can happen from time to time when typing lots of code.

Additionally utilizing a Boolean variable makes for less code (albeit not by much)  E.g.

```
Sub RetrieveWebPage(Inner as Boolean)
'... some code here
If Inner = True then
    rng.Value = cl.innerHTML
Else
    rng.Value = cl.outerHTML
End if
'... some code here
End Sub
```

A situation where a string parameter is more useful is when there are more than 2 outcomes that need to each be handled separately.  Just my two cents!  :)

Comment: Thanks for the respect :-). I agree with your general point. However the OP does refer to a possible third choice, i.e., "Title." I will amend my answer to make that clearer.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the misspelled String, though this limits the possible values to two only, no? As I wrote, I might have more than just two values that I might want to pass on.
And for simplicity, I did go with Tim Williams solution for the moment.